# Classic ASP sub procedure call in Response.Write

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic ASP question.

Attempting to do this: the recordset is a simple list of years from 1995 to 2020; and i am trying to make 2010(current year) the default selection in the drop down.

issue:  I trying to call a Sub proc in "Response.Write", but it keeps giving me this error:

> "Error '800a000d' Type mismatch: 'selectyear' "

Below is the code, the Attempt 1 works with out any problem. But when i move that "if" logic to a sub procedure and call it in the Request.Write, it gives me the error.

Can any one please explain why Attempt1 works and Attempt2 wouldnt.

```
' Attempt 1:

    rsYEAR.Open qYEAR, objconn, 0, 1 
    response.Write "<tr><td>Year:</td> <td> <select name='theyear' style=""WIDTH: 67px"">" 
    dim selyr
    while not rsYEAR.EOF
        if CINT(rsYEAR.fields("year")) = year(now) then
            selyr = "selected"
        else selyr = ""
        end if

        Response.Write"<option value='" & rsYEAR.fields("year") & "' "& selyr &" >"  & cstr(rsYEAR.Fields("year"))
        rsYEAR.MoveNext
    wend
    response.Write "</select></td></tr>"
    rsYEAR.Close


' Attempt 2: 

    rsYEAR.Open qYEAR, objconn, 0, 1 
    response.Write "<tr><td>Year:</td> <td> <select name='theyear' style=""WIDTH: 67px"">" 
    dim selyr2
    while not rsYEAR.EOF

        Response.Write "<option value='" & rsYEAR.fields("year") & "' " & cstr(selectyear(cint(rsYEAR.fields("year")))) &" >"  & cstr(rsYEAR.Fields("year")) 
        rsYEAR.MoveNext
    wend
    response.Write "</select></td></tr>"

    'close and clean up
    rsYEAR.Close
    set rsYEAR = nothing
```

I would greatly appreciate your response.
thank you,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that `cint(rsYEAR.fields("year"))` is throwing the error because there is data that cannot be converted to `int`. I would expect that to happen in both cases though.

You shouldn't need the `cstr` in `cstr(selectyear(cint(rsYEAR.fields("year"))))` in the second attempt, as I assume `selectyear` is already returning a string. Can you show the code for `selectyear`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.the SQL output is just list of years. I tried to convert using "cstr" before the SUB call, but that still gave me the same error.

Comment: Heres the code for Selectyear: sub selectyear(yr)
 if yr = year(now) then
  Response.Write "selected"
 else Response.Write ""
 end if
end sub

Comment: Ah - you should not `Response.Write` the value within `selectyear`, you should be returning the value from the `selectyear` function, since you are passing the value into 'cstr' (which you don't need to do), and then concatenating that to another string, which THEN gets output.

Comment: So make selectyear something like this: `function selectyear(yr) if yr = year(now) then selectyear = "selected" else selectyear = "" end if end function`

Answer (score 0):

(How has this sat for so long without a correct answer?)

A Sub does not have a value, so you can't Response.Write it. You need to either use a function, or put the Sub call on its own line.

```vbs
rsYEAR.Open qYEAR, objconn, 0, 1 
response.Write "<tr><td>Year:</td><td><select name='theyear' style=""width: 67px"">" 
dim y
while not rsYEAR.EOF
    y = rsYEAR.fields("year")
    Response.Write "<option value='" & y & "'" & IsCurr(y) & ">" & y & "</option>"
    rsYEAR.MoveNext
wend
response.Write "</select></td></tr>"
rsYEAR.Close

Function IsCurr(yr)
    if Cstr(yr) = Cstr(year(now)) then
        IsCurr = " selected"
    else
        IsCurr = ""
    end if
End Function
```

Using a sub instead of a function, this would become

```vbs
rsYEAR.Open qYEAR, objconn, 0, 1 
response.Write "<tr><td>Year:</td><td><select name='theyear' style=""width: 67px"">" 
dim y
while not rsYEAR.EOF
    y = rsYEAR.fields("year")
    Response.Write "<option value='" & y & "'"
    IsCurr y
    Response.Write ">" & y & "</option>"
    rsYEAR.MoveNext
wend
response.Write "</select></td></tr>"
rsYEAR.Close

Sub IsCurr(yr)
    if Cstr(yr) = Cstr(year(now)) then
        Response.Write " selected"
    end if
End Sub
```